# Why Python Mysql Query doesn't show all the columns whereas Phpmyadmin does it very well?

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, mysql-python

**Environment:**

Python 3.7
Mysql InnoDB

I am trying to collect data from different tables.
I have 4 tables:

- tasks,
- category,
- type_task,
- platform

When I execute my SQL request with Python, I get only 3 columns instead of 6:

```
import mysql.connector

"""
# Get list of tasks with:
    - id (from W551je5v_pb_tasks)
    - name (from W551je5v_pb_tasks)
    - introduction (from W551je5v_pb_tasks)
    - name_platform (from W551je5v_pb_platforms)
    - name_type_tasks (from W551je5v_pb_type_tasks)
    - category (from W551je5v_pb_categories)

"""

# =========================  MAKE A FUNCTION TO GET THE MYSQL CONNECTION  ==========================================
import mysql


def get_mysql_connection():
    """
    THis function will return the connection and cursor of our Mysql database
    """
    while True:
        try:
            mysql_connection = mysql.connector.connect(
                host="1.1.1.1",
                port=3306,
                user="reader",
                passwd="123456",
                database="db"
            )
            mysql_cursor = mysql_connection.cursor(dictionary=True)
            break

        except Exception as ex:

            print(
                f"Problem with Mysql Database!\n{ex}\nIt is certainly a problem of Internet connexion. PhoneBot will retry to run in 15 seconds.")

    return  mysql_connection, mysql_cursor
mysql_connection, mysql_cursor = get_mysql_connection()
SQL_DETAILS_OF_TASKS = f"SELECT tasks.id, tasks.name, tasks.introduction, platforms.name, type_tasks.name, categories.name \
                       FROM W551je5v_pb_tasks AS tasks \
                       INNER JOIN W551je5v_pb_platforms AS platforms  \
                       ON platforms.id = tasks.id_platform  \
                       INNER JOIN W551je5v_pb_type_tasks AS type_tasks  \
                       ON tasks.id_type_task = type_tasks.id  \
                       INNER JOIN W551je5v_pb_categories AS categories  \
                       ON platforms.id_category = categories.id  \
                       WHERE tasks.enable=1"
mysql_cursor.execute(SQL_DETAILS_OF_TASKS)
tuple_all_tasks_user = mysql_cursor.fetchall()
print(tuple_all_tasks_user)
for task in tuple_all_tasks_user:
    #print(f"{task} - {type(task)}")
    for column in task:
        #print(f"{column} - {type(column)}")
        pass
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
[{'id': 7, 'name': 'Cold Messaging', 'introduction': '<p>Hello</p>'},
 {'id': 8, 'name': 'Cold Messaging 2', 'introduction': '<p>Hello 2</p>'},
 {'id': 8, 'name': 'Cold Messaging 3', 'introduction': '<p>Hello 3</p>'}]
```

As you can see, the output doesn't show the platforms.name, type_tasks.name and categories.name columns.
So I did copy paste my SQL request in Phpmyadmin and I get successfully all my columns in the output.

[image]

I checked my foreign keys in the tables, I checked if tables were with innoDB. What else am I missing?
I changed the credentials for the admin mysql user in order to check if it was an issue with some privilege, but I get same result.

I export import the tables in my local mysql server with Wamp/Phpmyadmin. With root access to Mysql, I get same issue.
But if I execute the SQL in the phpmyadmin page, it works!

Can anyone reproduce the issue from his side please?

for me it seems to be an issue with python rather than SQL, doesn't it?

Did someone faced something similar?

Here are the SQL Tables to reproduce issue:

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 5.0.2
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Hôte : 127.0.0.1:3306
-- Généré le : sam. 22 mai 2021 à 11:26
-- Version du serveur :  8.0.21
-- Version de PHP : 7.3.21

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Base de données : `db_php`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Structure de la table `w551je5v_pb_categories`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `w551je5v_pb_categories`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `w551je5v_pb_categories` (
  `ID` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'ID',
  `name` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `slug` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `icon` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  `icon_blue_img` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  `icon_black_img` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  `icon_white_img` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `ID` (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=16 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Déchargement des données de la table `w551je5v_pb_categories`
--

INSERT INTO `w551je5v_pb_categories` (`ID`, `name`, `slug`, `icon`, `icon_blue_img`, `icon_black_img`, `icon_white_img`) VALUES
(1, 'Cold Messaging', 'cold_messaging', '<i class=\"mdi mdi-message-text-outline menu-icon\"></i>', '', '', ''),
(2, 'Influencers', 'influencers', '<i class=\"mdi mdi-human-greeting menu-icon\"></i>', '', '', ''),
(3, 'Scraping', 'scraping', '<i class=\"mdi mdi-database menu-icon\"></i>', '', '', ''),
(4, 'Authority', 'authority', '<i class=\"mdi mdi-shape-plus menu-icon\"></i>', '', '', ''),
(5, 'Freelancer', 'freelancer', '<i class=\"mdi mdi-worker menu-icon\"></i>', '', '', '');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Structure de la table `w551je5v_pb_platforms`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `w551je5v_pb_platforms`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `w551je5v_pb_platforms` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `image` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `color` varchar(7) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `id_category` int NOT NULL,
  `icon` varchar(300) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `icon_blue_img` varchar(300) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `icon_black_img` varchar(300) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `icon_white_img` varchar(300) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `application` varchar(900) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `url` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `id_category` (`id_category`),
  KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=41 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

--
-- Déchargement des données de la table `w551je5v_pb_platforms`
--

INSERT INTO `w551je5v_pb_platforms` (`id`, `name`, `image`, `color`, `description`, `id_category`, `icon`, `icon_blue_img`, `icon_black_img`, `icon_white_img`, `application`, `url`) VALUES
(3, 'Twitter', 'twitter_automation.jpg', '#1C9CEA', 'hello 1', 1, '<i class=\"mdi mdi-twitter\"></i>', '', '', '', 'Twitter', 'https://www.twitter.com'),
(4, 'Linkedin', 'linkedin_automation.jpg', '#0077B5', 'Helllo 2', 1, '<i class=\"mdi mdi-linkedin\"></i>', '', '', '', 'Linkedin', 'https://www.linkedin.com'),
(5, 'Leboncoin', 'leboncoin_automation.jpg', '#F76B14', 'Hello 3', 3, '', 'leboncoin_blue.png', 'leboncoin_black.png', 'leboncoin_white.png', 'Leboncoin', 'https://www.leboncoin.com'),
(15, 'Facebook', 'facebook_automation.jpg', '#1877F2', 'hello 4', 1, '<i class=\"mdi mdi-facebook-box\"></i>', '', '', '', 'Facebook_Orca,Facebook_Katana', 'https://www.facebook.com'),
(22, 'Instagram', 'instagram_automation.jpg', '#A42DB6', 'hello 5', 1, '<i class=\"mdi mdi-instagram\"></i>', '', '', '', 'Instagram', 'https://www.instagram.com'),
(27, 'Twitter', 'twitter_automation.jpg', '#1DA1F2', 'hello 6', 2, '<i class=\"mdi mdi-twitter\"></i>', '', '', '', 'Twitter', 'https://www.twitter.com');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Structure de la table `w551je5v_pb_tasks`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `w551je5v_pb_tasks`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `w551je5v_pb_tasks` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `introduction` text NOT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `id_platform` int NOT NULL,
  `id_type_task` int NOT NULL,
  `url_keywords` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `url_keywords_description` text NOT NULL,
  `minimum` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `minimum_description` text NOT NULL,
  `url_list` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `url_list_description` text NOT NULL,
  `url_usernames` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `url_usernames_description` text NOT NULL,
  `daily_limit` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `hourly_limit` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `enable` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `smartphone_allowed` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `computer_allowed` int DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `id_platform` (`id_platform`),
  KEY `id_type_task` (`id_type_task`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=36 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Déchargement des données de la table `w551je5v_pb_tasks`
--

INSERT INTO `w551je5v_pb_tasks` (`id`, `name`, `introduction`, `description`, `id_platform`, `id_type_task`, `url_keywords`, `url_keywords_description`, `minimum`, `minimum_description`, `url_list`, `url_list_description`, `url_usernames`, `url_usernames_description`, `daily_limit`, `hourly_limit`, `enable`, `smartphone_allowed`, `computer_allowed`) VALUES
(3, 'Group Members', 'intro 1', 'description 1', 15, 2, '0', '', '0', '', '1', 'list desc', '0', '', 15, 10, 1, 1, 1),
(4, 'Followers of accounts', 'intro 2', 'description 2', 22, 2, '0', '', '0', '', '1', 'list desc', '0', '', 20, 10, 1, 1, 1),
(5, 'Influencers', 'intro 3', 'description 3', 27, 1, '1', 'other descr', '1', 'other desc', '1', 'list desc', '0', '', 20, 10, 1, 1, 1);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Structure de la table `w551je5v_pb_type_tasks`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `w551je5v_pb_type_tasks`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `w551je5v_pb_type_tasks` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `description` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=13 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

--
-- Déchargement des données de la table `w551je5v_pb_type_tasks`
--

INSERT INTO `w551je5v_pb_type_tasks` (`id`, `name`, `description`) VALUES
(1, 'Message', ''),
(2, 'Voice Message', '<h3 class=\"card-title\" style=\"font-size:1.1em;\">                                         <i class=\"mdi mdi-format-align-left\"></i>                                         Text or Voice?                                     </h3>'),
(3, 'Scrape', ''),
(5, 'Publish Post', ''),
(6, 'Share Post', ''),
(7, 'Follow', ''),
(8, 'Unfollow', ''),
(9, 'Like', 'wxc'),
(12, 'Add Friends', 'This task is for adding friends');

--
-- Contraintes pour les tables déchargées
--

--
-- Contraintes pour la table `w551je5v_pb_platforms`
--
ALTER TABLE `w551je5v_pb_platforms`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `W551je5v_pb_platforms_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_category`) REFERENCES `w551je5v_pb_categories` (`ID`);

--
-- Contraintes pour la table `w551je5v_pb_tasks`
--
ALTER TABLE `w551je5v_pb_tasks`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `W551je5v_pb_tasks_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_type_task`) REFERENCES `w551je5v_pb_type_tasks` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `W551je5v_pb_tasks_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`id_platform`) REFERENCES `w551je5v_pb_platforms` (`id`);
COMMIT;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Comment: can you try aliasing the column names in your python sql query, something like `SELECT tasks.id, tasks.name as tname, tasks.introduction, platforms.name as pname, type_tasks.name as ttname, categories.name as cname ...` ? my guess is that they all have the same name `name` and python dicts can only have unique key names, which is why you only get one, not sure and hence leaving this as a comment, if this works for you I will write this as an answer

Comment: Bingo! :-) Thank you so much. I had to aliases all my columns

Comment: no problem. Go ahead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you connect to your database using `mysql_connection.cursor(dictionary=True)` returns rows as `dict`s. The property of a `dict` is that it can have unique keys, in your case all the columns have the same name in the table `name`. So there can only be one key of that `name`.

To overcome this you need to alias your column names like so

`SELECT tasks.id, tasks.name as tname, tasks.introduction, platforms.name as pname, type_tasks.name as ttname, categories.name as cname ...`.